# Python's Chatbot library

Tags: python, chat, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm searching for a simple way to clone myself from whatsapp conversation into a chatbot. I've tried [nmt-chatbot](https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot) and [chatterbot](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) , but i had problem with both reggarding the accuracy of the answers. So i'm wondering what alternatives there are, if those 2 are the best ones, and what is the most recomended for me.